# An array feed into to an Array list however with my own modifications

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a `input.txt` file that has the following bits line by line:

```
10100010
10010010
10110101
11100011
10010100
01010100
10000100
11111111
00010100
```

My code is printing out of the .txt file just fine, however now i need to put them in to an ArrayList with modifications... as in the array list will expand to size 12, because i will be always adding something new to the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 8th position of the arraylist.

So after each of 8 bit lines above, I want to have a seperate Array list for each line... however my code seems to add all to one big Array list named al

For example `x` denotes my own additions

`10100010` ---- Array  size 8

`xx1x010x0010`   ----- Array List   size 12

those `x`'s will be taken care later, but I want to have an array list be printing out to console or output file for each of the lines above in the `input.txt` file

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter file Name: ");

        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = getInput.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        FileInputStream fstream = null;

        try {
            fstream = new FileInputStream(file);

            DataInputStream in= new DataInputStream(fstream);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //print the content to console
                System.out.println(strLine);
                int[] n1 = new int [8];

                for(int i =0;i < strLine.length();i++) {
                    // System.out.println((strLine.charAt(i)));
                    n1[i] = Integer.valueOf(strLine.substring(i, i+1));
                }

                /*
                for(int n: n1)
                {
                System.out.println(n+" ");
                }
                */
                for(int i = 0; i < n1.length; i++){
                    al.add(0,1);  // dummy value for now 1st need to be changed
                    al.add(1,0);  // dummy value for now 2nd need to be changed
                    al.add(2, n1[0]);
                    al.add(3,0);  // dummy value for now 4th need to be changed
                    al.add(4,n1[1]);
                    al.add(5,n1[2]);
                    al.add(6,n1[3]);
                    al.add(7,0);   // dummy value for now 8th need to be changed
                    al.add(8,n1[4]);
                    al.add(9,n1[5]);
                    al.add(10,n1[6]);
                    al.add(11,n1[7]);
                }
            }

            int size = al.size();
            System.out.println(size);
            for(int j = 0; j < 12 ; j++) {
                System.out.println(al.get(j));
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        /*
         * try { System.out.println("Enter the name of Input file");
         *
         * Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in); String fileName =
         * getInput.nextLine();
         *
         * File f = new File(fileName+".txt"); InputStream f = new
         * FileInputStream(f);
         *
         * } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
         * block e.printStackTrace(); }
        */
        System.out.println("Even or Odd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all being added to `al` because you are adding them all to `al`. I think what you want is an ArrayList of ArrayLists. So, something like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> bitLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //print the content to console
    System.out.println(strLine);
    int[] n1 = new int [8];

    for(int i =0;i < strLine.length();i++){
        //  System.out.println((strLine.charAt(i)));

         n1[i] = Integer.valueOf(strLine.substring(i, i+1)); 

    }

    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0;i < n1.length; i++){
        al.add(0,1);  // dummy value for now 1st need to be changed
        al.add(1,0);  // dummy value for now 2nd need to be changed
        al.add(2, n1[0]);
        al.add(3,0);  // dummy value for now 4th need to be changed
        al.add(4,n1[1]);
        al.add(5,n1[2]);
        al.add(6,n1[3]);
        al.add(7,0);   // dummy value for now 8th need to be changed
        al.add(8,n1[4]);
        al.add(9,n1[5]);
        al.add(10,n1[6]);
        al.add(11,n1[7]);
    }
    bitLists.add(al);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop just repeats the following statements so many times

```
for(int i = 0;i < n1.length; i++){
  ...
}
```

and that's why all list elements are in one big list.

Simply omit the for statement, but keep the loop body.

**Later** Also,

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

should be moved into the loop reading the text file lines.